# SQLite.swift Alias in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift2, sqlite.swift

I am having an issue with Xcode (Prerelease 7.0 (7A218)) where alias function does not seem to work as expected (Or I am doing something wrong...)

This was working fine previously:

```
let preUsers = Table("PreUsers")
let eqowners = preUsers.alias("eqowners")
```

But now the compiler complains:

Value of Type 'Table' has no member 'alias'

As I understand from the documentation this should be working, I might be doing something wrong...

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: `alias` was temporarily removed during the upgrade. I'm going to try to get it in this weekend. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Thanks @stephencelis

Comment: @zzpaf I pushed basic alias support earlier today. Please let me know if this accomplishes what you need! It's incomplete (no way to alias subqueries...yet), but for basic joins it should work.

Comment: @stephencelis Working on the application, run into another issue with joins, will post separately to not confuse, once that is working I go into alias... At least it is compiling now, big improvement. Thanks for your awesome support

Comment: @stephencelis After getting past the other issue with joins, I was able to check the alias functionality and it is working correctly. As usually, thanks for the fast response time